# ngModel not binding on ngFor options inside select tag

Tags: html, angular

```html
<form>
 <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of ArrayObject">
          <td>
            <div>
             <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="p.tag" 
name="tag" #required>
               <option ngValue="YES">YES</option>
               <option ngValue="NO" >NO</option>
             </select>
           </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
```

I used ngFor to set a multiple select tag inside a form, it works without the form tag, but inside the form tag it seems that the value was not set correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "it seems that the value was not set correctly"?

Comment: @GCSDC my expected output of the loop was  NO,YES,YES but after adding the <form> tag  all value was defaulted to YES, it seems like [(ngModel)] is not working inside the <form> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add square brackets to ngValue to identify it as the [binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-way-in) target property. It should look like this instead `[ngValue]`

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of ArrayObject; let index = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
      <td>
        <div>
          <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="p.tag[index]" name="tag{{index}}" #required>
            <option [ngValue]="YES">YES</option>
            <option [ngValue]="NO">NO</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

On your component.ts, you will need to define the trackByIndex method:

```
// initialise with the following values to test if it is working
p = {
  tag: ['YES', 'YES', 'NO'] 
};

trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work, now all the dropdown is defaulted to blank.

Comment: @iconman and that is probabaly because `p.tag` on your component.ts is set to any value but 'YES' or 'NO'. Can I see your code on your component.ts? And how you assign the values to that property?

Comment: i set the property directy from API this.Service.getObject().subscribe(res => {
                      this.ArrayObject = res;}); <br> im pretty sure that the value was 'YES' and no as i displayed the value beside it using {{p.tag}}

Comment: What is `dps`? This looks like different from `p.tag`, isn't it? Anyways, your code is fundementally wrong, as the model is not even binded to the index. Let me make some changes.

Comment: thank you so much, i did include the index on the select name and now it displays as expected. it seems like the name must be unique for every control.

Comment: @iconman Ah, yes, I realise I myself initially forgot about making the names unique too! ngmodel actually requires the name attribute, thus it is important for it to be unique.